# MySQL vs DB2 RDBMS

Tags: mysql, database, db2

Is there s significant difference between the two? MySQL is used by YouTube, Google and Facebook while DB2 has the highest benchmark scores. Are there areas or cases where using a specific one would matter? Like size wise it is said that DB2 is really good on very small and very large databases (not sure why).

Any feedback or suggestions?

P.S. I'm more looking for functionality and capability differences.

Comment: i would say the main difference is the price but there's a bunch of differences like SQL dialects supported features. the question is really uhmm rhetorical.

Comment: Nothing has "the highest benchmark scores". Different systems perform differently with different workloads.

Comment: Take benchmarks with a grain of salt.  You should look at the benchmark itself to see what was tested, how it was tested, and whether or not the hardware was the same.  In a lot of cases there would be differences.

Comment: this isn't really the right place for "best of" type questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 is a real database manager, as Oracle, Informix, Sybase or MS SQL Server are.

MySQL is used to store data, but it is not a database with all the necessary features that a it implies.

For example:
DB2 has used the relation integrity from the beginning, not like MySQL that included this characteristic (since version 5, I think) and this feature is a fundamental part of a database (relational model according to Ted Codd's paper).

DB2 exploits the file system/storage, it uses different kinds of tablespaces to extract the data as fast as it can from the physical device. MySQL implement part of this feature, but not so long ago.

DB2 has different editions; the basic free edition, which is call Express-C, incorporates basic features, and just with that, it is even more powerful than MySQL.

The price is other factor. In the past, MySQL was an interesting Open Source project, but now it is part of Oracle. Currently, Oracle has finished the support to many of the Open Source projects that came from Sun (OpenOffice.org, Grid Engine, etc.) and we do not know the future plans for this database. Instead, IBM has released this basic version for "free" and the big blue keeps releasing the most recent version for free.

DB2 can run in many platforms: Windows, Linux, UNIX (AIX, HP-UX, Solaris). MySQL cannot run in all of them.

DB2 has many tools and features: disaster recovery (backup online/backup merge, restore full/incremental/delta); High availability (HADR); capability to scale to PureScale (DB in cluster); stores XML natively and retrieves them via xQuery/xPath; different isolation level; capability to write store procedures with SQL PL (IBM languange) and PL/SQL (Oracle language); automatic memory management (buffer pools, and other memory elements); and many many others features.

Many of these characteristics are included in the Express-C edition which is free.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thank you! Would there be a case where using MySQL would be more beneficial than using DB2 (or Express - C)?

Comment: MySQL could be use when you want to use a database without taking care about the performance, security or other factors, just something where to store the data in a structured way, and you do not plan to scale that architecture.

Comment: What do you mean by security and architecture?

Comment: The architecture is the description of the hardware characteristics where the database is stored, for example a small computer, with simple disks. And when you need to change that configuration (scale) to a cluster, with high availability, with RAID disks retrieving with a good performance and redundancy. DB2 could be configured for simple installation, but also for very complex configurations.

Comment: The security, is not only the data access, where DB2 has a powerful security system with a high granularity, but also the data security. I mean, how to solve a disaster problem, how to encrypt a backup, how to encrypt a table row, how to restore not only a full backup, but the database to the last second, or just a table space, or a table. Also, the security means, how to connect to the database via a secure channel.

Comment: But if a database is only being used on the intranet, and the amount of data is medium, would you still recommend DB2?

Comment: I'm not agree that this could be the answer. This answer based on the idea that MySql is not database at all. Only because 10 years ago it was not so cool.

Comment: Note DB2 also runs on the IBM i operating system (f.k.a. AS/400, iSeries, i5/OS) and is integrated into the operating system.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i  http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/db2/

Comment: check out db2 xml features http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/

Comment: Informative for DB2, But clearly biased answer in favor of DB2.

Comment: Doesn't even look like a fair comparison.